# Why isn't Rails::Railstie initializing after I installed CarrierWave gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, nameerror

Installed Carrier Wave gem successfully; added an image uploader which also works. However, when I went to rails db:migrate after changing a table, a name error popped up:

NameError: uninitialized constant Rails::Railtie. Did you mean? Rails.

Most of the other questions I've found online have to do with other uninitialized constants-- not Rails!

Here's the error called with --trace:

```
rails aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Rails::Railtie
Did you mean?  Rails
/Users/graceyang/.rbenv/versions/2.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.3.1/lib/carrierwave.rb:60:in `<module:CarrierWave>'
/Users/graceyang/.rbenv/versions/2.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.3.1/lib/carrierwave.rb:59:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/graceyang/Documents/Projects/JS Power/website/jspower/config/application.rb:2:in `require'
/Users/graceyang/Documents/Projects/JS Power/website/jspower/config/application.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/graceyang/Documents/Projects/JS Power/website/jspower/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/Users/graceyang/Documents/Projects/JS Power/website/jspower/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

None of my rails commands work anymore! I had just completed a successful rails g migration AddFieldNameToTable call before I called rails db:migrate and the error started.

***EDIT/UPDATE *** 
It works now with rake instead of rails db:
but if anyone can answer why, that would be great!

***EDIT/UPDATE ***
Actually, still a problem... can't install things that need the rails command....I found that the project was running under Ruby 2 for some reason even though my gemfile states gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.6'

Comment: Can you try with `bundle exec rails db:migrate`

Comment: please update your post include code from /Users/graceyang/Documents/Projects/JS Power/website/jspower/Rakefile:4 line and /config/application.rb:2 line, we need more information